# How to test internal function in container functional component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have to migrate my app from classes to functions. During refactoring I found two problems with unit tests.

1. How can I access the internal component function that renders another React component?
2. How to mock presentational component inside a container render method?

Consider two components:

ComponentToTest

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import {ViewToTest} from "./ViewToTest";

export function ComponentToTest(props) {
    const internalFunction = () => {
        return 'internal function'
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        internalFunction();
    }, []);

    return (
        <ViewToTest clientProductId={props.clientProductId} productShortName={props.productShortName}/>
    )
}

ComponentToTest.propTypes = {
    clientProductId: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    DataProductGeolocations: PropTypes.shape({
        clientProductGeolocationCountries: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
        loading: PropTypes.bool,
    }),
    productShortName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
ComponentToTest.defaultProps = {
    DataProductGeolocations: {
        clientProductGeolocationCountries: [],
        loading: false,
    },
};
```

and ViewToTest

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export const ViewToTest = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div>ViewToTest</div>
            <div>{props}</div>
        </>
    )
};

ViewToTest.propTypes = {
    clientProductId: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    productShortName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
ViewToTest.displayName = 'ViewToTest';
```

I wrote a simple test for ComponentToTest

```
import React from "react";

import {ComponentToTest} from "./ComponentToTest";

jest.mock('./ViewToTest', () => {
    return function MockedViewToTest(props) {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>clientProductId: {props.clientProductId}</div>
                <div>productShortName: {props.productShortName}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

describe('A ComponentToTest suite', () => {
    test('should match snapshot', () => {
        const component = shallow(
            <ComponentToTest clientProductId={666} productShortName={'lco'} />
        );

        expect(component.debug()).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    test('should call internalFunction() after first render', () => {
        const component = shallow(
            <ComponentToTest clientProductId={666} productShortName={'lco'} />
        );
        const instance = component.instance();

        expect(instance.internalFunction()).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

First test generates snapshot:

```
<Component clientProductId={666} productShortName=\"lco\" />
```

And the question is how to change mocked component name from *Component* to * ViewToTest*?

Second test failed with warning:

*Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.*

and error:

*TypeError: Cannot read property 'internalFunction' of null*

If you check what is *component* rendered with *shallow* you will see:

```
<Component clientProductId={666} productShortName="lco" />
```

instead of *ComponentToTest*

How should I write the test to have proper component name in snapshot and instance of *ComponentToTest* in second test?